# Jenkins running on AWS EC2 Windows instance - cannot find Jenkins job files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jenkins

So I've got Jenkins running on an AWS EC2 windows instance. I've created some test jobs and they run my Selenium automation scripts fine from Jenkins in my FF browser using localhost:8080.

I have Jenkins installed in C:\Jenkins. However, inside C:\Jenkins/jobs I see no files at all. Where are my Jenkins job files located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look under here:

```
C:\Users\<user that you use to run jenkins>\.jenkins
```

You can see your home directory clicking on:  Jenkins->Manage Jenkins->Configure System. That's where your job files should be.